# Divide data separated from ' - ' in one column into more in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Microsoft Excel and I was given a file where in one column there are two words separated from `-` (space, dash, space), i.e. there is something like this:

```
XXXXXX - XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXX - XXXXXXXX
XXXX - XXX
```

I would like to divide these words and put them into two different columns. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look at [For Loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) to loop through your range of cells and [the Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged the question with VBA but you've not posted any code.

A non VBA solution would be using TEXT TO COLUMNS. Just mark as delimiters the *space* and the *other* option (set it to `-`) and it will work properly:

[image]

When using TEXT TO COLUMNS, in step 1 choose `Delimited`. In step 2, do like this:

[image]

Third step, choose *Finish*

And you will get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop the cells, using `Split` to separate the data using "-" as the separator, and then write these to the appropriate cell.

```
Sub sSplitHyphen()
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngLast As Long
    Dim aData() As String
    lngLast = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For lngRow = 1 To lngLast
        If InStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, 1), "-") > 0 Then
            aData = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, 1), "-")
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, 2) = Trim(aData(0))
            ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, 3) = Trim(aData(1))
        End If
    Next lngRow
End Sub
```

I've used `Trim()` to remove the leading/trailing spaces. If all of your data is separated by " - " then you could use this to split the data.

Regards,